# zedgraph wont display the bars when i save it as image

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am trying to saveAs the zedgraph diagram that my program creates. The problem is that when i use that code it saves the image but only the labels on top of the bars appear...no bars are displayed.

```
 chart1.SaveAs();
```

Am i missing something?

The code that creates the  diagram:

```
GraphPane myPane = chart1.GraphPane;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.Format = "F0";
        //create the bars
        BarItem myCurve = myPane.AddBar("Width", pointPairListWidth, Color.Black);
        myCurve.Bar.Fill.Type = FillType.Solid;
        BarItem myCurve2 = myPane.AddBar("Height", pointPairListHeight, Color.Gray);
        BarItem.CreateBarLabels(myPane, false, "f0");
        chart1.AxisChange();
        chart1.Invalidate();
        chart1.Refresh();
```

ANSWER:

```
 chart1.GraphPane.GetImage().Save("pic.jpg");
```

Comment: please provide some more code. Hard to tell from this snippet.

Comment: @SatelliteSD i just added some more code as you requested.

Comment: was a long time ago since I've used zedGraph, but you are adding those bars to your myPane-object. So can you do myPane.SaveAs()?

Comment: Glad it helped :) I've edited my previous answer so you can mark this question answered.

Answer (score 0):

you could try `zedGraphControl.MasterPane.GetImage().Save("test.bmp")`

**Edit:**
was a long time ago since I've used zedGraph, but you are adding those bars to your `myPane`-object. So can you do `myPane.SaveAs()`?

Comment: It doesnt work. Moreover, when i minimize my program and maximize it it loses the bars too...